# How to manage stored procedure dependencies in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple stored procedures, some that depend upon others. When publishing my database, I receive an error when creating some stored procedures due to dependency issues. SSDT seems to be creating the stored procedures in alphabetical order, not dependency order like I need.

For example, suppose sp_ProcA depends upon sp_ProcB. SSDT is trying to create sp_ProcA first and fails because sp_ProcB hasn't been created yet.

I've looked through project and script settings. I've found nothing related to dependency management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which Stored Procedures are created in SQL Server should not, in most cases**, cause any errors. If dependent objects do not exist at the time of `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `ALTER PROCEDURE`, you should merely get a warning about SQL Server not being able to register the dependency in the meta-data (i.e. [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx)).

If you are getting an actual error, then most likely you have a certain build option set to do this. Go to **Project Properties** and then to the **Build** tab. There is a check-box for "Treat Transact-SQL warnings as errors". You probably have that checked. You can either un-check that option OR if you like having it to catch other warnings, then trying specifying the warning in the "Suppress Transact-SQL warnings:" text field.

---

** Linked Servers / OPENQUERY / OPENROWSET, by default, attempt to validate the remote schema unless you alter the Linked Server definition to specify `LazySchemaValidation`.

Comment: You were right, I had the "Treat Transact-SQL warnings as errors" property enabled.